# Intellisense unselected items invisible

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

In vs12 Ultimate Intellisense, only the selected item is visible, otherwise its a list of white lines with little icons to the left. The items appear as I scroll over them, then vanish. I tried the customize color editor, first filtering for "intel" then for "list" and made all foreground items dark enough to see but it didn't help. Its not obvious where intellisense gets its colors.

Comment: Solved, at least with my settings: Turns out intellisense uses the Main Menu Command Bar text color, but not the background.